# How do I make a subdirectory inside an svn repo an svn repo?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have checked out an svn repository with the structure:

```
/.svn
/trunk
/branches
/tags
```

How can I make the `trunk` folder the root of the repository and get rid of the rest, so that `trunk` becomes the new root with its own `.svn` folder? I'd like to do this without communicating with the remote.

Also I would like to know if it's possible to do the inverse of that - having downloaded an svn repo folder by folder, each folder is now a separate repo, I'd like to combine all the folders into a single repo.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you mixed up two things: changing the repository layout and checking out only a part of a repository. The later one will give you a directory with the content of the `trunk` folder and the hidden `.svn` folder. To do so you just add `/trunk` to your URL during the checkout, e.g. `svn checkout <OldUrl>/trunk <LocalPath>` or shorthand from `svn co <OldUrl>/trunk <LocalPath>`

You can change the repository layout easily after checking out the whole repository. Just rearrange your folder as you like (using SVN commands --> Tree changes) and then commit your changes.

Comment: Can I checkout a part of repository that I've already checked out, like `svn checkout <LocalURL>/trunk <AnotherLocalPath>`? Or do I need a running svn server on my computer to do that?

Comment: You can create as much working copies as you like, SVN does not track the single working copies